# How can I clear a line in console after using \r and printing some text?

Tags: python, linux, console

For my current project, there are some pieces of code that are slow and which I can't make faster. To get some feedback how much was done / has to be done, I've created a progress snippet which you can see below.

When you look at the last line

```
sys.stdout.write("\r100%" + " "*80 + "\n")
```

**I use `" "*80` to override eventually remaining characters. Is there a better way to clear the line?**

(If you find the error in the calculation of the remaining time, I'd also be happy. But that's the question.)

### Progress snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import sys
import datetime


def some_slow_function():
    start_time = time.time()
    totalwork = 100
    for i in range(totalwork):
        # The slow part
        time.sleep(0.05)
        if i > 0:
            # Show how much work was done / how much work is remaining
            percentage_done = float(i)/totalwork
            current_running_time = time.time() - start_time
            remaining_seconds = current_running_time / percentage_done
            tmp = datetime.timedelta(seconds=remaining_seconds)
            sys.stdout.write("\r%0.2f%% (%s remaining)   " %
                             (percentage_done*100, str(tmp)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write("\r100%" + " "*80 + "\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_slow_function()
```

### Consoles

I use ZSH most of the time, sometimes bash (and I am always on a Linux system)

Comment: depends on what your console is. e.g. a unix vt100-type console has completely different line-clearing semantics than a Windows console.

Comment: Why do you ask if there is a better way? What happens when you try this way?

Comment: @Robᵩ: The problem is that I have to know how much I have to override.

Comment: @MarcB: I use ZSH and Bash (and I am always on Linux systems).

Comment: so look up ansi/vt100 terminal control sequences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the ANSI/vt100 "erase to end of line" escape sequence:

```
sys.stdout.write("\r100%\033[K\n")
```

Demonstration:

```
for i in range(4):
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + ("."*i*10))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if i == 3:
        sys.stdout.write("\rDone\033[K\n")
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
from msvcrt import putch, getch

def putvalue(value):
   for c in str(value):
      putch(c)

def overwrite(value):
   """ Used to overwrite the current line in the command prompt,
   useful when displaying percent or progress """
   putvalue('\r'+str(value))

from time import sleep


for x in xrange(101):
   overwrite("Testing Overwrite.........%s%% complete" % x)
   sleep(.05)
```